# yield always gets called

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield

Currently I'm reading a collection of items from a stream. I do this as following:

```
public class Parser{

 private TextReader _reader; //Get set in Constructor
 private IEnumerable<Item> _items;    

 public IEnumerable<Item> Items{
  get{
   //I >>thought<< this would prevent LoadItems() from being called twice.
   return _items ?? (_items = LoadItems());
  }
 }

 public IEnumerable<Item> LoadItems(){
  while(_reader.Peek() >= 0){
   yield return new Item(_reader.ReadLine()); //Actually it's a little different
  }
 }
}
```

Let say I have a stream which contains two items, and I do the following:

```
var textReader = //Load textreader here
var parser = new Parser(textReader);
var result1 = parser.Items.Count();
var result2 = parser.Items.Count();
```

Now `result1` is 2, while `result2` is one.

Now I noticed, that my null check is useless? It seems that everytime I call that function it gets yielded anyway.

Can someone explain to me why this is? And what would be the best solution for this situation (please tell me if what I'm doing is complete crap :P).

Comment: yup, it should yield every time since you are not assigning '_items' variable anywhere so its always null and load items is called every time.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but ain't I assigning it here `_items = LoadItems()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `LoadItems` is a lazy enumerable (uses `yield`) and you are assigning it to a field, it means that every time you enumerate `_items` you are actually causing the loop within `LoadItems()` to be run again, i.e. (`Enumerable.Count` creates a new `Enumerator` each time which cause the `LoadItems` body to be run again). As you are not creating the reader afresh each time within `LoadItems` its cursor will be positioned at the end of the stream so will likely not be able to read any more lines — I suspect that it is returning `null` and your your single `Item` object returned on the second call contains a `null` string.

Solutions to this would be to 'realise' the result of `LoadItems` by calling `Enumerable.ToList` which will give you a concrete list:

```
return _items ?? (_items = LoadItems().ToList());
```

Or seeking the reader back to the beginning of the stream (if possible) such that `LoadItems` can run again each time identically.

But I would recommend you simply get rid of the `yield`ing in this case and return a concrete list as there is little benefit so you are paying the complexity price for no gain.

Comment: That's what I figured. But when you're exhaustively reading a resource and yield-returning the items. How can you make sure you don't lose the resources.

Comment: You can preserve the result of the reader by realising the read lines into a concrete list, either by calling `Enumerable.ToList` on the resultant `IEnumerable` or by constructing a `List<>` (or other data structure) manually, e.g. `LoadItems().ToList()` or `new List<Item>(LoadItems())`.

Comment: Aah thanks! I totally got the idea of the yield wrong! Thanks for explaining it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name has led you astray. At the moment:

```
 private IEnumerable<Item> _items;
```

you are lazy-loading and saving the **iterator**, whereas you probably want to be lazy-loading and saving the **items** (as the variable name suggests):

```
public class Parser{

 private TextReader _reader; //Get set in Constructor
 private List<Item> _items;    

 public IEnumerable<Item> Items{
  get{
   return _items ?? (_items = LoadItems().ToList());
  }
 }

 private IEnumerable<Item> LoadItems(){
  while(_reader.Peek() >= 0){
   yield return new Item(_reader.ReadLine()); //Actually it's a little different
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider that `yield` is used as short hand. Your code gets turned into something like:

```
private class <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide : IEnumerator<Item>
{
   private TextReader _rdr;
   /* other state-holding fields */
   public <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide(TextReader rdr)
   {
     _rdr = rdr;
   }
   /* Implement MoveNext, Current here */
}
private class <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide2 : IEnumerable<Item>
{
   private TextReader _rdr;
   /* other state-holding fields */
   public <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide2(TextReader rdr)
   {
     _rdr = rdr;
   }
   public <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide GetEnumerator()
   {
     return new <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide(_rdr);
   }
   /* etc */
}
public IEnumerable<Item> LoadItems()
{
    return new <>ImpossibleNameSoItWontCollide2(_rdr);
}
```

Hence `LoadItems()` is indeed only called once, but the object it returns has `GetEnumerator()` called on it twice.

And since the `TextReader` has moved on, this gives the wrong results for you. Though do note that it leads to a lower use of memory than holding onto all the items, so it's got benefits when you don't want to use the same set of items twice.

Since you *do* want to, you need to create an object that stores them:

```
return _items = _items ?? _items = LoadItems().ToList();
```

Comment: Ah awesome, I really like this answer because you explained what the syntactic sugar of yield actually does!

Comment: You're welcome. It's worth adding, that if you'd put a `using` block into `LoadItems` to dispose the `TextReader` when you were finished, then the `Dispose()` method of the enumerator would dispose it (but not the enumeration, so if the enumeration wasn't actually enumerated through, then it wouldn't be called).